# on_stage_instance_delete event listener not printing the stage_instance's id

Tags: pycord

There is a listener in my code for `on_stage_instance_create` and another for `on_stage_instance_delete`. Whenever I create a stage, the `on_stage_instance_create` function will post the `stage_instance.id` and `stage_instance.topic` in a logging channel.

Whenever I delete/end the stage, `on_stage_instance_delete` is not fired. It prints when I restart the bot or reload the extension while there is an active stage which I end/delete, only then function works.

Code Snippet

````
    def __init__(self, bot: discord.Bot) -> None:
        self.bot = bot

        self.classes_log_channel_id = 1150871569690800188
        self.topic = None
        self.instance_channel = None
        self.instance_id = None
        

    @commands.Cog.listener(name="on_stage_instance_create")
    async def on_stage_instance_create(self, stage_instance: discord.StageInstance) -> None:
        db = await aiosqlite.connect("./user.db")
        await db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS classes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, instance_id INT, channel_id INT, instance_topic INT, entered_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )")

        self.topic = stage_instance.topic
        self.instance_id = stage_instance.id
        self.instance_channel = stage_instance.channel_id

        await db.execute("INSERT INTO classes (instance_id, channel_id, instance_topic) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (self.instance_id, self.instance_channel, self.topic))
        await db.commit()
        await db.close()
        # guild = self.bot.get_guild(guildid)
        # verified_role = guild.get_role(verified_role_id)
        
        # class_channel = self.bot.get_channel(self.instance_channel)
        # await class_channel.set_permissions(verified_role, view_channel=True, connect=True)

        classes_log_channel = self.bot.get_channel(self.classes_log_channel_id)
        if self.topic:
            await classes_log_channel.send(f"STARTED - Topic is {self.topic}, in {self.instance_id}")
        else:
            await classes_log_channel.send("No Ongoing Class")
        return
    
    @commands.Cog.listener(name="on_stage_instance_delete")
    async def on_stage_instance_delete(self, stage_instance):
        if stage_instance.id is self.instance_id:
            print("Stage Ended")```

I moved the `on_stage_instance_delete` under the same decorator of `on_stage_instance_create`, no results.

Added a print statement and it only prints when I restart the bot or reload the extension then delete an already active stage instance.
````